# Batch File. Open and Exit WMP12 after Video File is done

Tags: video, batch-file, mp4, exit

I have a HTPC (Home theater PC) which has a THX Video that plays on start up. The video starts with WMP 12 and I have it set to play automatically and go to full screen automatically.

Problem is WMP (Windows Media Player) 12 doesn't support the /close argument so I am trying to create a batch file that will recognize the completion of the file "thx.mp4" and exit WMP.

Can anyone help me out with this?

HTPC Runs:
Windows 7 Pro
Windows Media Player

Comment: how should the batch recognize the end of the video? How do you do this from command line (without a script)?? I can maybe make a script for you, but I will **not**  google for several options of obscure video players.

Comment: Maybe the WMP closes handle over the `thx.mp4` file once it finished playing it.

Comment: The OP has to find out how his program works. This is not a batch programmer task.

Answer (score 0):

You could install VLC and use that to play the intro:

```
@echo off
set "file=c:\path\thx.mp4"
start "" /w /max "c:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe" "%file%" vlc://quit
```

Comment: Well in terms of how WMP works...I only know how the UI works. Programming is not my skill so in terms of how it works in the background, I don't know. I'll try the VLC player. I do have that. I'll let you know. 

I read this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6702856/close-a-running-application-from-dos-command-line . Someone got WMP to close from a batch file which recognized a MP3 or something. You guys know more than me.